The issue is that in the quantum circuit, the lines on the second and fifth rows are broken (discontinuous). How can this be corrected?

\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{quantikz}

\crefname{Quantikz}{quantum circuit}{quantum circuit}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=qua, listname={List of Quantum Circuits}, placement=ht] {Quantikz}

\begin{document}
    \listofQuantikz
        \begin{quantikz}
        \lstick{$\ket{0}$}&\gate[6]{V_1}&\gate[3]{U_{x_0}}&\gate[6]{V_2}&\gate[3]{U_{x_0}}&\ \ldots\ &\gate[6]{V_K} &\meter{} \\
        \lstick{$\hspace{-0.7cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}$} \rstick{$\hspace{5.7cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots} \hspace{2.6cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}$}\\
        \lstick{$\ket{0}$}&&&&&\ \ldots\ &&\meter{}\\
        \lstick{$\ket{0}$}&&&&&\ \ldots\ &&\\
        \lstick{$\hspace{1.8cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}\hspace{-2.6cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}$} \rstick{$\hspace{5.7cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}\hspace{2.6cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}$}\\
        \lstick{$\ket{0}$}&&&&&\ \ldots\ &&
    \end{quantikz}
   
   \begin{quantikz}
    \lstick{$\ket{0}$} &\gate{H}& \ctrl{1} & \gate{H} &  \meter{} \\
    \lstick[8]{$\ket{\psi}$} && \gate[8]{U}&&  \\
    &&&& \qw   \\
    &&&& \qw   \\
    &&&& \qw   \\
    &&&& \qw   \\
    &&&& \qw   \\
    &&&& \qw   \\
    &&&& \qw  
   \end{quantikz}
\end{document}


Welcome to TEX.SE! Would you mind posting a complete document code, so we don't have to guess the preamble? Also, it may help you find a solution to be a bit more clear in what you're asking for.

I realized the reason for this is that the quantum circuit diagram placed behind this one, the lines become discontinuous, but both diagrams taken individually are perfectly correct, which is just a very, very strange thing to do！

I think this is essentially the same issue covered in this answer

The issue here is essentially the same as seen in the question Quantikz circuits bugs in TexStudio. If a circuit is not fully drawn (a line in the circuit has insufficient & to cover the whole length) then blanks that would have been left for a multi-line element such as a unitary are inserted the next time that cell is printed in any circuit.
The second and penultimate lines are the issue here, the solution is to fill them, setting the wiretype to not print. However it's worth noting you can also get more natural alignment in the circuit by inserting the relevant cells rather than using the manual \hspaces you have.
I would replace
\lstick{$\hspace{-0.7cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}$} \rstick{$\hspace{5.7cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots} \hspace{2.6cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}$}\\

with
\lstick{$\hspace{-0.7cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}$} \setwiretype{n} & & & & & \boldsymbol{\vdots} & & \boldsymbol{\vdots} \\

and
\lstick{$\hspace{1.8cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}\hspace{-2.6cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}$} \rstick{$\hspace{5.7cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}\hspace{2.6cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}$}\\

with
\lstick{$\hspace{-0.7cm}\boldsymbol{\vdots}$} \setwiretype{n} & & \boldsymbol{\vdots} & & \boldsymbol{\vdots} & \boldsymbol{\vdots} & & \boldsymbol{\vdots} \\

